# Get an error "An error occurred during report data sets execution" while trying to print any report

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I use:

Application release: Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations (July 2017)

Platform release: Update 8 (7.0.4565.16212).

When I try to print **ANY** report I get the following error message: [image]

What I've tried:

1. First of all build + synchronize of all models
2. Redeployed all reports using Power Shell script
3. Checked that report's (not of all, but only the one I need) data source tables are all of TempDB type
4. Checked settings in "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" - Web Service URL and Web Portal URL are correct.

I've got no more ideas how I can fix that issue.

Comment: Did you try to check both EventViewer and SSRS log? Do they give you some more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in SSL certificates.

So you can solve the issue following steps below:

1) go to environment which causes the errors in Lifecycle Services

2) there click Maintain => Rotate secrets => choose "Rotate secrets" tile on the right side (see 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 pictures below)

3) Click "Yes"

It took about 20-30 minutes to rotate them. After that i didn't get any errors when printing reports.

1.1

[image]

1.2

[image]

1.3

[image]